# Is it OK to create 2 instances of C# MongoClient connecting to the same replica set?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I used to create an instance of `MongoClient` from the official driver and register it in the DI as a singleton. But now because of design issues, I have to create another MongoClient instance in the other place to connect to the very same Replica Set.

Are there any potential problems? Do the two instances will use the same connection or create two separate connections?

Project is written in ASP.NET Core 3.1
MongoDB driver's version 2.8
MongoDB server uses 4.2

Comment: i cannot verify this but i've read that the c# driver will use the same connection pool for multiple `MongoClient`s if they use exact same set of settings. if you need verification you would have to look at the driver source on github or just have a look at the mongodb log. it should show how many connections are opened for each client.

Comment: As I see in the [constructor](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoClient.cs#L81) `MongoClient` ensures it uses same cluster so should be safe I think.

Comment: It uses same cluster and or creates one as needed as @ViacheslavShchupak mentioned already.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, if all client options are the same, it will work since the underlying mongo client's data is stored on the cluster level. And as it was mentioned in the comments above, mongoClient constructor tries to retrieve this data from the static storage each time when you create a new client.

However, there is a restriction, your MongoClientSettings should not contain the configured ClusterConfigurator option. Otherwise, it will lead to creating two different clusters with all related stuff for example connection pools.

Also, see `Re-use` section here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/connecting/