# How to utilize MongoDB connection pooling with multiple CRUD services in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

MongoDB docs says that in order to utilize their native pooling with multiple IMongoClient instances, the settings between each of those instances must be the same. I assume they mean connection string, database name, and collection name. I have three collections (User, ChatRoom, and ChatMessage) for a Chat App. The connection string and database name will be the same for the three collections. ***IF*** the collection name must be the same as well, does this mean it's not possible to utilize Mongo's native pooling for multiple collections in the same database? Otherwise, I should be able to create three CRUD service classes, inject IMongoClient into each class and change the collection name to the corresponding class.

QUESTION: When it comes to databases (SQL and NoSQL), does the pooling only at the table/collection level or does it apply to the entire database. If the latter is true, then I would think the collection name differences wouldn't disable the pooling in Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionName` has no value in this context. It's only about connectionString (or MongoClientSettings). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281767/is-it-ok-to-create-2-instances-of-c-sharp-mongoclient-connecting-to-the-same-rep/62225894#62225894) for details.

> or does it apply to the entire database.

it applies to the whole MongoClient. Database name will have meaning only if you specify it in auth credentials or connection string.